# Dual Monitor setup detected as single screen

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, docking-station

Two similar monitors display the same picture and are shown as a single monitor under `Ubuntu` in `System Settings -> Displays`. This is a `DELL Latitude e5550` laptop and both displays are connected via two `DVI` interfaces through `DELL E-PORT PLUS II DOCKING STATION`.

```
lspci | grep -iE "vga|3d|2d"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

[image]